# Printer not printing to the bypass tray

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, printing, network-printer

I have a Ricoh 5501 and I installed the PCL 6 Driver for Windows 10 x64. One machine just will not print to the Bypass Tray and the other prints just fine when changing the tray.

Is there something I am missing or something I should do to troubleshoot this issue further?

Comment: If there's a particular document you see this with then be sure to check that document's Page Setup setting from the Paper tab and ensure the tray is not explicitly specified at the document level. Assuming it's a Word document. This may not be the case in this instance but I wanted to mention just in case as I've seen this stump many many people where the document level settings overrides the OS printer preference settings, etc. If it's one document, this could be the problem so just be thorough with this respect.

Comment: When you try to print to the bypass, does the machine:

a) Do nothing, as if nothing was sent.
b) Throw an error on the screen (if so, can you provide the wording).
c) Print, but to the wrong tray.

There's a few little snags that you could have hit, and this will help determine which.

Answer (score 1):

At work, we are using the C5503, so there shouldn't be a lot of differences.

- Make sure you are pointing the Bypass tray from the printing
  settings.
- Make sure you fill the Bypass tray ONCE you've sent the files to the 
  printer.
- Make sure the user have permissions to print from the Bypass tray.
- Make sure your Bypass tray is activated in the Printer's parameters.

It is one huge printer with a lot of settings and possibilities, so make sure everything goes fine.

If you need more specific help, we can chat on Hangouts.